# Update multiple ubuntu installation throw lan

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I have ~15 Ubuntu Desktop PC connected to a same router.

I want to update them (with apt or something else like it) with single download.

for example: I update admin PC packages and another PCs updated automatically or update with my commands but don't download anything and use admin's downloaded packages.

so How do I setup this process?

Comment: (I guess) You'll need to update one PC them follow one of the above answers to duplicate apt from that PC to other 14 PC's || But their might be better ways to do this

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for - but a nice solution: apt-cacher-ng. This allows you to have a single machine handle the update-fetch process. All other machines will query the apt-cacher instance and use it as a proxy.